# Small trouble with a regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, regular-language

I need to build a regular expression, with the following details. The regular expression needs to match in the following chars structure:

### ***`OT-001-16`***

1. `OT`: They may be uppercase or lowercase, but I only need to match if it is `O` followed by `T`, not `T` and followed by `O`.
2. `-` Followed by this character.
3. `001` Followed by 3 or more numbers.
4. `-` Followed by this character.
5. `16` And finally followed by exact 2 numbers.

This is what I've tried:

```
/([OT|ot]{2})-(\d{3,})-(\d{2})/g
```

This regular expression works fine, except if I write `TO-0052-54`, the problem is with the `OT` chars, I need to match only if a `O` is followed by `T`.

Thanks and any question post on comments.

Comment: `/(OT|ot)-(\d{3,})-(\d{2})/g` try this

Comment: @Prajwal Oh! I was close. Your solution works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by using `[OT|ot]{2}` you are actually comparing a string that has char O or o and T or t of length 2. It is like using something like this.

`[ABCD]{2}` : where it matches all the possibles combinations of characters.

To solve this, use `(OT|ot)` which matches between this particular pattern OT or ot.